# Web API is not reading my type on POST

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, urlencode

I'm trying to send some data over POST to my Web API but my data is always read as null.

I am sending it as form data

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

It is working in a different project of mine, but not here, it's very strange.

My type is like this:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public List<string> Headers;
    public List<QueryResultLine> Results;
}
```

My request is like this:

```
[Route("export/excel")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostExportToExcel(QueryResult queryResult)
{
    DoSomething(queryResult);
}
```

Whenever I make this request queryResult.Headers and queryResult.Results is null.

> Headers=%5B%22Nummer%22%2C%22Omschrijving%22%2C%22Locatie%22%2C%22Beheerder%22%2C%22Niveau%22%2C%22ArtikelNummer%22%2C%22Naam%22%2C%22InhoudL%22%2C%22InhoudKG%22%2C%22Voorkomen%22%2C%22Opslag%22%2C%22Seveso%22%2C%22CLP%22%2C%22Uitvoering%22%2C%22Voorziening%22%2C%22HPZinnen%22%5D&Results=%5B%7B%22Nummer%22%3A%22DECO.1%22%2C%22Omschrijving%22%3A%22Testvat%22%2C%22Locatie%22%3A%22Testvat+chem%22%2C%22Beheerder%22%3A%22SIDCCEO%22%2C%22Niveau%22%3A0%2C%22ArtikelNummer%22%3A%22AM00632548%22%2C%22Naam%22%3A%22Tetrahydrothiophene+-+Scentinel++T+Gas+Odorant%22%2C%22InhoudL%22%3A150%2C%22InhoudKG%22%3A150%2C%22Voorkomen%22%3A%22verplaatsbaar+recipi%C3%ABnt%22%2C%22Opslag%22%3Afalse%2C%22Seveso%22%3A%22P5c%22%2C%22CLP%22%3Anull%2C%22Uitvoering%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Voorziening%22%3A%22%22%2C%22HPZinnen%22%3A%22H312%2C+H315%2C+H332%2C+P280%2C+P501%2C+H302%2C+H225%2C+H319%2C+H412%2C+P210%2C+P233%2C+P240%2C+P241%2C+P242%2C+P243%2C+P264%2C+P270%2C+P301%2B310%2C+P303%2B361%2B353%2C+P330%2C+P331%2C+P370%2B378%2C+P403%2B235%2C+P405%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A210%22%7D%5D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whenever I make this request queryResult.Headers and
>   queryResult.Results is null

`Headers` and `Results` are not bound during model binding because they are declared as fields, not properties. Default model binder will bind only properties. Check [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690403/Public-Field-Not-Bound-When-Pos) for further details.

So you should adjust definition of `QueryResult` to:

```
public class QueryResult
{
    public List<string> Headers { get; set; }

    public List<QueryResultLine> Results { get; set; }
}
```

For query body that you provided, `Headers` property will be deserialized as a list with one string which is

> ["Nummer","Omschrijving","Locatie","Beheerder","Niveau","ArtikelNummer","Naam","InhoudL","InhoudKG","Voorkomen","Opslag","Seveso","CLP","Uitvoering","Voorziening","HPZinnen"]

I believe this is not what you expect and you need all those values added as separate strings in the list.
To achieve this you should fix the request sent from the client. Following request body will be correctly deserialized to list of values:

> Headers=Nummer&Headers=Omschrijving&Headers=Locatie&Headers=Beheerder&Headers=Niveau&Headers=ArtikelNummer&Headers=Naam&Headers=InhoudL&Headers=InhoudKG&Headers=Voorkomen&Headers=Opslag&Headers=Seveso&Headers=CLP&Headers=Uitvoering&Headers=Voorziening&Headers=HPZinnen

As you see, for building a list, `Headers` is just repeated with different values.
Request part for `Results` should be adjusted in the same way.

Comment: Thanks, that's a dumb little thing I never noticed!